# Can a link list have more than one head node?

Tags: java, list, hyperlink, nodes, head

I am trying to create a Link List in which there will be multiple head nodes. For example the list would be formatted like this

5->4->3->7->8

|

6->3->9->2->12

|

3->5->2->9->13

I am able to create a link list in which I have a head node and then other nodes are added into the list but am unsure how to create a new head node. I will be reading the data from a text file.

Comment: *Can a link list have more than one head node?* - No. if it does, it becomes a tree or a graph, not a linked list anymore.

Comment: Use `LinkedList<LinkedList<?>>`.

Comment: I don't know about Java, but in C it is fairly straight-forward to create three lists, for sake of example, where the third element in list 1 is the 'next' element of the fifth element in list 2, and where the sixth element in list 1 is the next element of the fourth element of list 3.  That is, the three lists have distinct starts, but they end up pointing to the same set of nodes at the end of list 1.  Such a scheme is a recipe for disaster if you free all the elements on list 2 (not that freeing is a problem in Java; it is in C, though).  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ Now it comes down to semantics; in my example, I identified 3 lists each with its own head.  They share some common nodes, though.  Each of the lists has just one head node.  You can obviously (well, in the C world, it is obvious) have multiple copies of the pointer to a head node of a list, but that's still one list.  I'd argue that each list has a head node separate from each other list, even if they share some portion of the tail.  You can also have a loop in a list. possibly with multiple side-chains leading into the list-with-a-loop.